# how to change CSS file from html head with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two CSS files for a html file, I have placed the first `Redesign` CSS file inside HTML head section as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/Redesign.css">
```

& second file `greyscale` CSS is also placed in same folder but not added in head section.
Now I wanted to change the CSS file `Redesign.CSS` to `greyscale.CSS` when user click on image id `home_owl` & vice-versa

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-xs-7">
<img class="owl_header_img" alt="" id="home_owl" src="../xxx/static/images/owl_main.png" /></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click','#home_owl',function (){  $('link[href="Redesign.css"]').attr('href','greyscale.css');});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the equals selector, where you probably want to be using the ends with selector in your jQuery code. Here is a list of the selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

You probably want something like this (assuming greyscale.css lives in the same folder as Redesign.css).  Notice that I am using $= instead of = in the selector for the link. Also note that I updated the updated href to include the relative path for greyscale.css.

```
$(document).on('click','#home_owl',function (){  $('link[href$="Redesign.css"]').attr('href','static/css/greyscale.css');});
```

If you wanted to use the equal selector and not the ends with selector you're going to have to change the code to the following, because "=" means an exact match:

```
$(document).on('click','#home_owl',function (){  $('link[href$="static/css/Redesign.css"]').attr('href','static/css/greyscale.css');});
```

Comment: but it reverse the CSS on page refresh

Comment: When the page refreshes, so do all of the changes made by jQuery.  If you want these changes to persist, you will have to save them in some way, either save them a session or cache  variable, then check that variable on page load.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot, I just removed the localStorage part while posting it here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to change jQuery code to:

```
$(document).on('click','#home_owl',function (){  $('link[href="static/css/Redesign.css"]').attr('href','static/css/greyscale.css');});
```

You wrote this code `link[href="Redesign.css"`, but the href attribute of the link is `"static/css/Redesign.css"`, so you need to change it to match. Otherways, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a new link tag in the head, with your href.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click','#home_owl',function (){          jQuery('link[href="Redesign.css"]').remove();
 jQuery('head').append( '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/greyscale.css">' );
});
```

```css
#home_owl{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="owl_header_img" alt="" id="home_owl" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-1r804nM74p8/UxWnBSGO9fI/AAAAAAAAAYQ/cFWlwjHbjkw/s1600/Click-Here-Blue.gif" />
```